# invalid subscript type 'list' Azure Machine Learning

Tags: r, lapply, azure-machine-learning-service

**PROBLEM**

I deployed my experiments in Azure Machine Learning as a Web Service. The experiments ran without error.

But when testing using `REQUEST/RESPONSE`, I'm getting the error below:

> Execute R Script Piped (RPackage) : The following error occurred during evaluation of R script: R_tryEval: return error: Error in split(df, list(df$PRO_NAME, df$Illness_Code))[Ind] : invalid subscript type 'list'

This is the code:

```
# Loop through the dataframe and apply model
Ind <- sapply(split(df, list(df$PRO_NAME,df$Illness_Code)), 
              function(x)nrow(x)>1)

out <- lapply(
    split(df, list(df$PRO_NAME, df$Illness_Code))[Ind],
    function(c){
        m <- lm(formula = COUNT ~ YEAR, data = c)
        coef(m)
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FIXED**

**Problem:**

Some R codes don't work if input data is limited (e.g 1-2 rows only)

**Solution:**

Load data by `Batch` instead of `REQUEST/RESPONSE`